# validate XML against XSD in asp.net4.0

Tags: xml, xsd

I am using following code to validate XML against XSD in asp.net4.0.

```
 static int ErrorsCount = 0;

    public static void ValidationHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs args)
    {
        //ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage + args.Message + "\r\n";
        ErrorsCount++;
    }

    public bool validate(String xml)
    {
        XmlTextReader tr = null;
        XmlSchemaCollection xsc = null;
        XmlValidatingReader vr = null;
        string XSDLocation = string.Empty;
        xsc = new XmlSchemaCollection();
        XSDLocation = "D:\\PENN Universal Gateway\\Penn.Common.Shared\\Schema\\s2sPlayer.xsd");

        tr = new XmlTextReader(XSDLocation);
        xsc.Add(null, tr);
        vr = new XmlValidatingReader(xml.ToString(), XmlNodeType.Document, null);
        vr.Schemas.Add(xsc);
        vr.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
        vr.ValidationEventHandler -= new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationHandler);
        vr.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationHandler);

        while (vr.Read()) ;
        vr.Close();
        if (ErrorsCount > 0)
        {
            return false;

        }
        return true;
    }
```

> this function always return me **False** thats is not valid for valid XML,XSD also.
>   plz suggest what is going wrong here...

Comment: You are using ancient techniques. Don't use `XmlTextReader` or `XmlValidatingReader`. See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlvalidatingreader.aspx) that shows this is obsolete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your handler is always called, and all the handler does is increment the error count. So ErrorsCount will always be > 0 and your method will always return false.

Or am I missing something?